# How to keep up with the public repo?

Tags: git, laravel, github

I'm hosting my Laravel project as a private repo on GitHub. What bothers me is that I'm not up to date with the latest changes of the project.

For example take a look at these Pull requests:

- [Bump package versions](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3726/files)
- [Fixed up the phpunit config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3725/files)
- [Use ComposerScripts](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3699/files)
- [Set HttpOnly flag](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3697/files)

These are all (more or less) useful fixes which I want to adapt in my current installation. What I do at the moment is to take a look at my GitHub notifications, see if there is something going on in the laravel repo and - if yes - copy/paste them. This works, but it's not easy to keep up with the changes and it's not comfortable either.

Is there a way to improve this workflow? For example by cloning the public repo and merge these changes somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you clone GitHub project its becoming "your" project and you have to manage the code.

What you can do is simply to pull the changes from the `upstream` (original project) like you do in any other git project.

https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that github do not provide webpage button to allow you to update your forked repository.

If you cloned your forked repository to your local PC, you can add the original repository as the second remote. After added new remote, you can fetch updated source code from original reposity and merge with branched which track your private repository, then push to your private repository.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but there's no easy way to keep up to date with the project scaffold, especially considering you're likely to make your own changes to the setup for each project.

It's worth keeping an eye on changes to the repo, otherwise coming back every now and again to inspect what's new. You can look through commits to get an overview of what has changed.

Generally I'll pull down a fresh copy of the repo every now and again and then diff it against my projects. Keeping in mind changes I've made for my projects specifically, I'll merge the relevant changes back into my repos.